# Unknown database error - Invision Power on MAMP

Tags: database, ipb

I am trying to install invision power board (Version 3.1) on MAMP. Everything is going well except for this part. It keeps saying that there is an unknown database ipbtest, but I have created the database with the name ipbtest already through phpMyAdmin lite. Please advise? Thank you. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error because my database name had a leading space when I created it in the `phpMyAdmin` console.

Make sure your database name is '`ipbtest`' and not ' `ipbtest`'.